# Isolated DC voltage measurement via optocoupler

Tags: dc, opto-isolator, voltage-measurement, isolation, tl431

I am trying to make a circuit that measures 10-30V DC with isolation. The measurement is done by the circuit, not manual. The measured voltage level/information is sent via an optocoupler to the ADC pin of a microcontroller. For example, the microcontroller reads 15.36V. I am hoping 50mV accuracy. I have looked at the linear optocoupler photoconductive circuit. Figure 19 in this link https://www.vishay.com/docs/83708/appnote50.pdf

I have used two [CNY17-2](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81863/cny17.pdf) general optocouplers in place of one linear optocoupler. But, it generates different outputs when I replace one optocoupler with another optocoupler from the same model. The difference is high enough to produce high error. So, I guess the use of two general optocouplers does not work for this circuit as I have to implement the circuit on multiple units.

I have tried voltage to frequency conversion technique using a 555 timer. But, the error is very high.

I will avoid digital isolators and isolation amplifiers for now due to their cost.

Are there any other techniques, or circuits that I can implement cheaply? Mainly hoping to implement this using general optocouplers. Probably some mathematical methods that compensate error of the general optocoupler? Can TL431 be utilized somehow?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can the 10 to 30 volt side support 20 mA or so for some circuitry? Does the required solution absolutely need to produce an analogue voltage that feeds an ADC.

Comment: @Andyaka, yes, it can support other circuitry, and it can support additional 20mA. The plan is that ADC of the microcontroller reads this. But, do you have other ideas that requires other than ADC? If so, please share.

Comment: Since you mention cost, what is your budget?

Comment: @elec3 - Hi, It's not allowed to make such major changes to a question after you've received answers. It makes the answers look wrong / incomplete. Therefore I have reversed (rolled-back) your edit. Please don't do that again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inexpensive ~1W DC:DC converter to create an isolated supply, then use an ADC or MCU with an ADC, and transmit digital data using something like serial asynch communication (which would require only a single opto).

There are optocouplers which are designed for linear use - they have a single LED which illuminates two photodiodes, but they still require some adjustment (the single LED approach does eliminate a good part of the thermal and aging effects).

There are also some relatively inexpensive isolation amplifiers designed for current sensing (100mV or so input full scale) so I also suggest surveying those parts before making decision.

Answer (score 1):

On the isolated side (the side that has a voltage varying between 10 volts and 30 volts whose value you want to transmit to an MCU on the non-isolated side), you could power a 5 volt regulator to provide a stable voltage for a small circuit. That small circuit would generate a ramping voltage on a fixed time base of (say) 10 milli seconds (for example).

Then, use a comparator with one input connected to the ramping voltage I just mentioned. The other input can connect to a voltage divider that "pots down" the 10 volt to 30 volt supply so that you get a measurement voltage that is within the 5 volt and 0 volts limit of the comparator and ramping voltage.

So, when the comparator switches, this can be seen on the non-isolated side using an opto-isolator. But, you also need to transmit a sync signal from the isolated side via another opto to the non-isolated side: -

[image]

The end game is that the MCU reads the output of two opto-couplers. A positive output edge from the sync opto output informs the MCU that a ramp has just began. When that opto goes low, the ramp has finished. Somewhere between those two time limits, the opto connected to the comparator changes state.

So, if you know the lower voltage limit of the linear ramp and, you know the upper voltage limit of the linear ramp then you can calculate what voltage the comparator senses when it switches.

Hope that makes sense. It won't be massively accurate but, in its benefit, you will be using the optos digitally thus avoiding temperature effects that plague using an opto linearly. I think also there may be ways to reduce the opto count to one.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a PWM signal proportional to the voltage you need to measure, and pass it to the processor through an optoisolator. where asimple RC filter can provide a DC signal for an ADC. Here is a simulation showing the basic idea.

[image: PWM Simulation]

This principle is used in a 600V current monitor [IR2175](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2175(S)-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c9161216c6), although it uses level shifting rather than opto-isolation, and the PWM carrier is 130 kHz, making it unsuitable for driving an optoisolator.

Comment: Duty cycle modifications (due to temperature) through a low-grade opto can be significant as I once found to my cost many years ago.

Comment: Can be massively improved with two Optos for push-pull operation or with a "digital isolator IC" to transmit the PWM

Comment: @Andyaka, why does duty cycle depend on temperature? The response time of the CNY17-3 is typically 5 us and maximum 10 us, which are not very significant at 1 kHz. And a 4N25 has typically 2 us. However, a photodarlington like ILD55 has 10 us rise time and 35 us fall time, so it would not be suitable. And logic output optos like TLP2355 have response times as fast as 100 ns, and pulse width distortion under 70 ns, for about a dollar. https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TLP2355_datasheet_en_20191119-1079430.pdf

Comment: I said low grade optos.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the heads up about this possible issue. Most of the optos I looked at were cheap 25 cent/1 devices, and yet appeared to be good enough, at least for 1 kHz. I couldn't find any relevant parameters that were affected by temperature. Could you give details about the ones you used, and the reason for the dysfunction? I have found some specs for "propagation delay skew" as well as additional delay from saturation, but they were insignificant.

Comment: It was back in the 1990s so no, I can't remember models by rise and fall times were asymmetrical and drifted with temperature. I might have been using them at circa 50 kHz.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that I am using. [Here is the data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1311.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1694390685315&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Famc1311)  There are different versions of the "isolation amp" from different companies.  This one inputs 0 to 0.2V while I use the one that inputs 0 to 2V.  It does need 5V or 3.3V power on both sides.
[image]